# What would intersection of set $C$ be?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $I=\varnothing$.

For each $a\in I$, let $B_a$ be a set and $C=\{B_a:a\in I\}$ (then $C$ is collection of sets).

If we were to define $\bigcap C=\{x\in B_a:x∈B_a\text{ for all }a\in I\}$, **what would** $\bigcap C$ **be?**

My thoughts that $B$ does not exist, so $C$ is $\{\varnothing\}$, so $\bigcap C=\varnothing$.

Comment: Since there are no $B_a$'s, $C=\emptyset$. Therefore $\bigcap C$ seems somewhat ill-defined (which, as I understand things, stems from the attempt to define this set by means other than comprehension).

Comment: @JonathanY. Ill-defined as a set, but not as a class.

Comment: @TrevorWilson, thanks. I've seen (and appreciated) your answer. I'll defer to your discretion as to whether to remove these comments or let them stand for the clarification.

Comment: @JonathanY. I think it's usually best to let such comments stand.

Comment: Please consider accepting answers to some of the 20 questions you have asked so far.

Comment: @Trevor Wilson. ??? How do I do that?

Comment: @NadiaC You can accept an answer to one of your own questions by clicking the check mark next to the answer.

Comment: @Trevor Wilson. Ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $I = \emptyset$, then $C = \{B_a : a \in I\} = \emptyset$ (not $C=\{\emptyset\}$.) Therefore $\bigcap C = \bigcap \emptyset$ is the universal class $V$.  That is, every set is in $\bigcap C$ because for every set $x$ the statement "$x$ is in $B_a$ for all $a \in I$" is vacuously true.